Реализация авторизации на сайте
Как лучше в данный момент реализовывать хранение куков?
Cлышал что гугл в 2025 году, откажется от поддержки куков. Не могу утверждать...
В данный момент, записываю php/sessionid в отдельную таблицу и сохраняю в куки браузера.
Открываем страницу, смотрим на значение сохраненных куков, ищем в бд...
Что та подсказывает, что не верно так делаю... И как быть, когда браузеры перестанут поддерживать куки и куки уйдут в прошлое?

У вас искаженная информация: гугл откажется от сторонних кук, а не от локальных. То есть всяким метрикам, рекламным меткам и прочему мусору станет жить сложнее, а сам сайт свои же куки сможет свободно использовать.
